# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name:

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm trying to submit reactive form with form arrays, I've tried solutions from other threads but none worked for me, I feel like I'm missing something. Exact errors are ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'stepName' and ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'stepDesc'. Here is a sample code:
Html:

```
<div formArrayName="knowSteps" cdkDrag *ngFor="let formGroup of knowSteps.controls; let i = index">
            <div [formGroup]="knowSteps.controls[i]">
              <mat-accordion>
                <mat-expansion-panel class="step-expand">
                  <mat-expansion-panel-header cdkDragHandle class="drag-drop">
                    <p>{{steptitle.value == '' ? 'Step' : steptitle.value}}</p>
                  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  <div clas="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12  p-3 mb-2 step-name" >
                      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Step Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="stepName" name="stepName" #steptitle>
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div clas="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12  p-3 mb-2 step-description">
                      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                        <mat-label>Step Description</mat-label>
                        <textarea matInput formControlName="stepDesc" name="stepDesc"></textarea>
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Please ignore the not closed divs from the form.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.knowhowForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    knowSteps: this.formBuilder.array(
     [[this.knowledgeStepsForm()]],
  )
});

  knowledgeStepsForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
    stepName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    stepDesc: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  })
}

 get knowSteps(): FormArray {
   return this.knowhowForm.get('knowSteps') as FormArray;
 }
```

My submit form:

```
createKnowledge(){
   this.newKnowledge.knowledge_steps = this.knowhowForm.get('knowSteps').value;
}
```

I've placed only this part of the form since this is the only part that doesn't work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Although you may perceive that this is the only part which doesn't work, omitting code makes it harder for us to assist you. If possible, please post a "working" example (at least, working enough to show the problem) on Stackblitz.

Comment: Sorry about this, next time I'll try to prepare a problem using stackblitz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    stepName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    stepDesc: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  })
```

should be called before `ngAfterViewInit` is reached. Usually in the `constructor`/`ngOnInit`.

Comment: Thank you that actually worked. Initially, I thought including this.knowledgeStepsForm() in ngOnInit would do the same, but obviously not.

Comment: I'm glad. If this worked for you can you also upvote? Happy coding :)

Comment: That was the first thing I wanted to do, but it says I have less than 15 reputation